# is there any bulk_update django2.0?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to save a thousand records; some of them need to be inserted (created) and some need to be updated if the PK already exists.

How can I achieve this in Django 2.0 ?

Comment: Would it be possible to separate those objects that have a PK? Then you can use `bulk_create()` for one group and `update()` for the others.

Comment: for the update, I need to loop through each and every object it is taking me time. is there any solution to update? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality for bulk update in django.  But you can use the [django-bulk-update](https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update) app and save the list with just two sql queries:

```
from django_bulk_update.helper import bulk_update

bulk_update(obj for obj in my_list if obj.pk)
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(obj for obj in my_list if not obj.pk)
```